# apex:outputlink not working

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, visualforce-component

I have overridden the Accounts View with VF page and when opened in console the link in related list does not  work.

Like, I have a contact in contact relatedlist  and when I click on the link nothing happens. I feel like the apex:outputlink is not working. Below is the code I am using in the page.

```
< apex:pageblockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="c" rendered="{!Contacts.size>0}" rows="5">               
   < apex:column headervalue="Action">               
     < apex:outputLink style="text-decoration: none;color:#015BA7" 
                       value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Edit,c.Id)}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
   </apex:column> 
   <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>    
   <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" >    
     <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.ID}" target="_blank">{!c.Name}</apex:outputLink>  
   </apex:column>
```

The Edit link in relatedlist also does not work.

Any suggestions what I need to change in the code.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
mrp

Comment: What exactly do you mean by doesn't work?  Does nothing happen?  Does it take you to the wrong page?

Comment: Often the 'rendered' attribute can cause problems - try removing that. Failing that, inspect your page and see if any other errors crop up.

Comment: If you "View Source" on the rendered page, what do those Edit and View links look like?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (and handles the rendered problem)

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
 <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:variable var="csize" value="'{!Account.Contacts}'"/>
  <apex:variable var="csizeEmpty" value="'[]'"/>

  <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="c" rows="5" rendered="{!csize != csizeEmpty}}">               
    <apex:column headervalue="Action">               
      <apex:outputLink style="text-decoration: none;color:#015BA7" 
                       value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Edit,c.Id)}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
     </apex:column>     
     <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" >    
     <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.ID}" target="_blank">{!c.Name}</apex:outputLink>  
     </apex:column>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But, first, a few words from our sponsors - in this case, a brilliant post by @LaceySnr here: http://www.laceysnr.com/2013/02/two-visualforce-methods-for-conditional.html

Getting a list's size in VF using the `.size` property does not work if you are not referring to controller collections. In your case, you are referencing the standard controller's `Account.Contacts` related list.  LaceySnr shows how to test for the absence of rows by comparing the string value of `Account.Contacts` to `[]`

As a second note, your VF code wouldn't compile because there was a space between the left angle bracket and the apex token.

If the page is named 'Foo', then /apex/Foo?id=someAcctId will display a page where the outputlinks work as expected